# a bytes-like object is required, no 'str' with pickle python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pickle

I am struggling to get this code fix with python3.6 on my macos, although this code used to run on python 2.x
Keep getting this errors a bytes-like object is required, no 'str' and unable to make it work although changing code around by 'r' -> 'rb' "w" ->"wb" or pickle.load(f) pickle.loads(f)

for the function write() also get error "write() argument must be str, not bytes"

here is link for full code 
https://pastebin.com/embed_js/7tsdP9J6

```
#This is for saving params
if iter % SAVE_PARAMS_EVERY == 0 and useSaved:
        save_params(iter, x)

def save_params(iter, params):
    with open("saved_params_%d.npy" % iter, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(params, f)
        pickle.dump(random.getstate(), f)


def load_saved_params():
    """
    A helper function that loads previously saved parameters and resets
    iteration start.
    """
    st = 0
    for f in glob.glob("saved_params_*.npy"):
        iter = int(op.splitext(op.basename(f))[0].split("_")[2])
        if (iter > st):
            st = iter

    if st > 0:
        with open("saved_params_%d.npy" % st, "rb") as f:
            params = pickle.loads(f)
            state = pickle.loads(f.read())
        return st, params, state
    else:
        return st, None, None
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback so we see exactly which line causes the error?

Comment: `params = pickle.loads(f)` looks odd to me - `loads` expects a bytes object but you're passing it a file...

Comment: I just add a code in pastebin link.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python's official documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads

`pickle.load()` expects an opened file object to be passed as a first positional argument, whereas `pickle.loads()` expects `bytes` object. Note the `encoding="ASCII"` parameter as well. Speaking of `encoding`, the documentation states that you can set it to `bytes` to let `pickle` read 8-bit string instances as `bytes` objects.

I have never used `pickle` before and therefore can't give concrete answer but maybe try rewriting your snippet like this:

```
with open("saved_params_{}.npy".format(st), "rb") as f:
    file_contents = f.read()
    # use pickle.load(file_contents) from now on
```

Actually, when you do `f.read()`, entire file contents will be read and file cursor will point to the end of the file. When you use `read()` next time, there will be no contents left for you to read, because the first call already "consumed" entire file. Maybe that is the problem, because in second call to `pickle.read()` you pass empty file contents?

Hope it helped a bit :)

Comment: when use "r" it get the above error, but when I change to "rb" i get "ran out of input" error. still confusing